# Symfony send options from FormType CollectionType to FormType

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to know if there is any way to send an option from a form type with `CollectionType` to another form type.

```
$builder->add(
    'contact', CollectionType::class,
    [
        'entry_type' => ContactType::class,
        'data' => [
            'options' => 'confirmResa'
        ]
    ]
);
```

I know we can send option with this `data` by using `$builder->getData()` in the second form type but when it's a `CollectionType`, I think it take the `data` for him instead of using it for the `entry_type`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok nevermind I find a solution, I've already use in my last project.

So the answer is to use `entry_options` and sending `data` in the `entry_options`

cf: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-options

Solution:

```
$builder->add('contact', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => ContactType::class, 
    'entry_options' => ['data' => ['confirmResa']],
]);
```